# How do I execute a function on-close or on dismiss of <paper-dialog> for Polymer 1.0?

Tags: dialog, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

**Question:**

> How do I automatically execute a function whenever my `<paper-dialog>` element is closed?

**Version:** Polymer 1.0

**Code:**

```
<paper-dialog id="paper-id"
              entry-animation="scale-up-animation"
              exit-animation="scale-down-animation">
    <sample-element></sample-element>
</paper-dialog>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`paper-dialog` inherits the `Polymer.IronOverlayBehavior`, which has the `iron-overlay-opened` and `iron-overlay-closed` events.

```
<paper-dialog
  on-iron-overlay-opened="_myOpenFunction"
  on-iron-overlay-closed="_myClosedFunction"></paper-dialog>
```

- https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@polymer/iron-overlay-behavior
- code: https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-overlay-behavior/blob/master/test/iron-overlay-behavior.html (for example: take a look at line 147 for the `iron-overload-opened` event)

Comment: They are working to improve that.  At the moment, I recommend exploring the linked Behaviors at the bottom of the page of a component, as the component will inherit any Properties or Methods of those Behaviors.  Soon they will be able to include them directly in the component documentation, which should make events like these easier to find.

Comment: Yes agree with you, Thanks a lot @Zikes

Comment: Thanks, @Zikes. Oddly, I couldn't get this to work. I defined an independent function that I passed in like you have above, but the callback wasn't firing. I got this to work using the method, `addEventListener('iron-overlay-closed')` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Even this is old topic, there is still 1 thing that people should know and be aware of:

I highly recommend you to also check `event.target` inside your listener function. For example, if you have another element using `iron-overlay` inside `paper-dialog`, closing that elements will trigger listener on `paper-dialog`. (you can try this with `vaadin-date-picker`).

So:

```
<paper-dialog on-iron-overlay-closed="_myClosedFunction"></paper-dialog>
```

and then `_myClosedFunction`:

```
_myClosedFunction(e) {
  if(e.target.nodeName == "PAPER-DIALOG") {
    //...toDo stuff...
  }
}
```

Now you are guaranteed that whenever only paper-dialog is closed, your code will be executed